# What does this sentence with "If ... and upon ..." mean?

Tags: meaning

> **If practical and upon a reasonable and timely request**, the manager in
>   charge may conduct a test firing of a firearm.

What does the bold part mean? Does it mean "if the request is practical and reasonable, and if the request is made in a timely manner"?

Comment: The text looks "awkward" to me without a comma after ***practical***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is two separate conditions. Those conditions are:

1. **If** it is **practical** to do so *and*
2. **Upon a reasonable and timely request**

The two things on either side of the *and* are independent of one another.

Thus, the manage in charge can conduct a test firing of a firearm if they make a request that is both reasonable and timely (a word that can have multiple interpretations, and it's hard to be sure which is meant here), and it is practical to do so. The practicality test is of the test firing, not of the request; the tests applied to the request are just that it is reasonable and timely.